# Multiple server behind one public IP address

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

so I am setting up my home network with multiple Raspberry Pis and I have run into an issue, which might be similar, but not exactly identical to some other queries here on stackoverflow. I am just starting so this might be a pretty newbie question.

Here is the setup: I have a router (a pretty shitty one as we rent the apartment from someone who had the network set up) and want to connect three Raspberry Pis with different functions:

- RPi 1 is running a Apache2 Webserver and hosting my owncloud instance. As I do not have a static public IP I am using noip.com to dynamically update a domain to resolve to my current IP - address.
- RPi 2 is running a VPN service which I want to be able to use while being on the road, e.g. in Internet Cafés and such.
- RPi 3 has a RPi Noir Camera v2 and serves as a Baby Monitor which is accessible via its private IP address within the network.

So, here comes the question: is there a way to access each of these raspberries via their private IP addresses from outside my network?

I.e. I want to be able to access the owncloud, the VPN and the baby monitor via their respective private IP - addresses? Or do I need to find a way to run all these services on a single machine?

Thanks and sorry for asking basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on the router.

For example:

for external IP / port 1234 -> forward to internal IP (and possibly different port) of RPi 1

for external IP / port 1235 -> forward to internal IP of RPi 2

and so on..

I use port 1234 as an example for the webserver, because there could be problems when using port 80 on a home network. To access it you can use `yourPublicIP:1234/index.html` (or dynamic_domain:1234 )

Comment: I see how this would work for different services and prootocols. But the Baby Monitor e.g. is reached via a browser window.So if I type in the public IP I **always** land on the owncloud server as it runs the webserver on port 80. 

So would it be as easy as assigning the baby monitor a different port?

Comment: @mor3dr3ad Yes, I was still editing / adding to the answer. From the outside you'll probably need to use a port above 1024 (could be depending on the ISP), then in the router you can forward this to an internal IP and possibly a different port (like port 80).

Comment: @mor3dr3ad If you are allowed to use port 80 from the outside, you could use this (leave as it is) to reach your owncloude server. To access the Baby monitor you could use publicIP:1235 from the browser and forward this to internalIP:80. This way you can keep the Baby monitor on port 80 if you want. Of course you would need to build in some security.